# Using K.tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax() with an 3D input tensor

Tags: python, keras, max-pooling

I would like to implement the SegNet for 3D images (width, height and depth, where depth is not channels). Thus in the decoder part of the network I need the pooling indices.
The function K.tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax() only works for 2D images (width and height).
There is a function MaxPooling3D but this only returns the tensor after the pooling operation without the indices.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Hi ! Did you check this thread yet?                                 
 https://pretagteam.com/question/using-ktfnnmaxpoolwithargmax-with-an-3d-input-tensor